# Problems using character ' for derivatives in questions for Canvas

Tags: r-exams

I am creating differential equation questions for uploading in Canvas via zip QTI. As you may think I write something like

```
\[ y'' + y = x+1 \]
```

in the body of the question. I tested the question in a HTML display and it was ok, BUT when I build a QTI file for Canvas and upload it, the formula was not correctly displayed.

A workaround is to replace y'' with \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} which displays correctly but simply y' would be preferred.

Comment: The question editor deleted the backslash character in my formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the issue only occurs when using Rnw exercises but not with Rmd exercises and when using the `pandoc-mathml` converter (while `pandoc-mathjax` would work correctly, for example). It can also be replicated using `exams2html()` when using the following options that correspond to the setup used in Canvas:

```
exams2html("diffeq.Rnw", converter = "pandoc-mathml", mathjax = TRUE)
```

Luckily there is a simple workaround, namely in Rnw exercises use `y^{''}` instead of the `y''` that you would use in Rmd exercises. And then make sure you use `converter = "pandoc-mathml"`. See below for simple worked examples for the exercise files.

R/LaTeX version: `diffeq.Rnw`.

```
\begin{question}
Is this differential equation showing up correctly?

\[ y^{''} + y = x+1 \]

\begin{answerlist}
  \item Yes
  \item No
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\exname{differential equation}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{10}
```

R/Markdown version: `diffeq.Rmd`.

```
Question
========
Is this differential equation showing up correctly?

\\[ y'' + y = x+1 \\]

Questionlist
------------
* Yes
* No

Meta-information
================
exname: differential equation
extype: schoice
exsolution: 10
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it works and solves your problem please remember to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left, next to the answer. If it should not be fully solved yet, please refine the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply professor Achim. But the error still remains. Where the equation should appear Canvas display a message "Unexpected text node".

Comment: Is there a way to add an image in stackoverflow?

Comment: Did you try setting `converter = "pandoc-mathml"` explicitly? I only got the unexpected text node error when using the ttm converter.

Comment: After adding [converter = "pandoc-mathml"] your solution affectively solve the problem: CANVAS displays derivatives correctly. Thanks!!

Comment: I have adapted my answer to clarify this. Please accept the answer now so that it is resolved here on StackOverflow.